# How to delete cookie while closing the browers tab using servlet cookie

Tags: java, servlets, session-cookies

```
{    
final Cookie cookies = new Cookie(key, value);
cookies.setMaxAge(-1);
response.addCookie(cookies);
}
```

by setting the `MaxAge = -1` will clear the cookie when the browser being closed. But I want to clear the cookie while closing the tab.

Comment: have you tried any java script code ? to delete cookie from browser

Comment: I don't want to depend on front end(JS). So i want to delete the cookie by using only back end code(java).